# iOS app with InApp after 30 days

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

I am developing an app, where users able to sign up and try out the app for 30 days, after 30 days user wants to make IAP to continue with the app.
On IAP I decided to make 3 plans : 6 months, 1 year and Life Long scheme.

1. Will this be considered as a trial app?
2. Will this be allowed by Apple Team (blocking complete app from usage and then uses IAP to continue rather than making a paid app)?

Comment: As far as I remember IAP auto renewable subscriptions offers trial period check on the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html

Answer (score 1):

No Trail apps are not allowed by Apple, this is covered by [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

> **2.9** Apps that are "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected. Beta Apps may only be submitted through TestFlight and must
>   follow the TestFlight guidelines

Comment: I've successfully submitted an app that offered a trial period and later asks for a full purchase. I guess that it should be read as "not fully functional app". I also use and app (Sleep Cycle) that offers a 30 day trial and later asks for purchase

Comment: Actually in my app all features are available for for 30 days, so Apple will consider this as a trial version ?

Comment: I second @Andrea have done this in some apps and submitted. They go through fine. You should not have a problem getting the app approved

Comment: Previous review are not a guarantee then Apple will allow your app.

Comment: I also agree with @rckoenes comment. We can't guarantee based on previous reviews. I want to know that is the above one will considered as a trail version if I submitted ?